# Nested ReflectionExtractor in Coherence

Tags: oracle-coherence

I can't find is there a possibility to use nested fields in ReflectionExtractor?
For example, if I have

```
String field = myObj.getKey().getField()
```

this code

```
new ReflectionExtractor("getKey.getField")
```

throws an error

```
 Missing or inaccessible method: MyClass.getKey.getField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is ChainedExtractor for it: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/util/extractor/ChainedExtractor.html.